# findFragmentByTag always returns null

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

Where am i going wrong. I just want to check if the fragment with the given ProductId is already available in the BackStack;

If yes than dont add the new Fragment otherwise add the current fragment to the backstack.

```
public void showThisFragment(Fragment newFragment,int productId){
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.am_fragment_holder, newFragment);
    if(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(productId+"")==null){
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(productId+"");
    }else{
        //TODO fragment already present
        //So dont add to the back stack
    }    
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

please help!

Comment: You have to add the fragment to the backstack with a key, which is different than adding a fragment with a key in the first place.   Or you can lookup the key by searching the backstack directly.  There's a good writeup [here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9702216/get-the-latest-fragment-in-backstack)

Comment: I cannot add it using the key.., in my case tags is what i have. Can you help me with some changes in my present code.

Answer (score 1):

There is no tag added to replaced fragment. You should use three argument replace method. I did not test it so tell me if I am right.

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.am_fragment_holder, newFragment, String.valueOf(productId));
```