# Navigate to respective fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I used TabNavigation in my application. But I am facing difficulty in move back to respective fragment .In my application I have multiple fragment.I implement B fragment with single button which is navigate  to A fragment only.
But I am sending data from many fragment to  B but  I am facing difficulty in  navigate to respective fragment.Ex  if am send data from C to B then I want move back to C instead of A. or if  I send data from D-B  then I want to move back D.Could you tell me how could  I solve this issue.Because In B fragment’s Button I have written code for navigate to A only.Please any one tell me how I solve this issue.
I am attaching code here

In A .code for send data to B

```
B  b==new B();
                  Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                  CarBean carbean=new CarBean();

                                   carbean.setName(txt_cardesc.getText().toString());
                  carbean.setPrize(txt_carprize.getText().toString());
                  carbean.setAvgPrize(txt_vat.getText().toString());
                  carbean.setImage("R.drawable.img"+currentposition);
                  carbean.setArrayList(mylist);
                  bundle.putParcelable("data", carbean);

                  carfragment.setArguments(bundle);
                  mActivity.pushFragments(com.media.contractcar.base.AppConstants.TAB_HOME, b, true, true);
```

In B

```
mActivity.pushFragments(com.media.contractcar.base.AppConstants.TAB_HOME, new A(), true, true);
```

In C.Code for data is send to B

```
 B  b==new B();
                  Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                  CarBean carbean=new CarBean();

                  carbean.setName(txt_cardesc.getText().toString());
                  carbean.setPrize(txt_carprize.getText().toString());
                  carbean.setAvgPrize(txt_vat.getText().toString());
                  carbean.setImage("R.drawable.img"+currentposition);
                  carbean.setArrayList(mylist);
                  bundle.putParcelable("data", carbean);

                  carfragment.setArguments(bundle);
                  mActivity.pushFragments(com.media.contractcar.base.AppConstants.TAB_HOME, b, true, true);
```

In B

```
mActivity.pushFragments(com.media.contractcar.base.AppConstants.TAB_HOME, new A(), true, true);
```

But problem is How could I navigate to C.If I send data from different fragment then I want move back to respective fragment.

Comment: try this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9702216/get-the-latest-fragment-in-backstack

Comment: Thanks for reply prakash.could you tell me in details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `BackStack` and keep data of where you come form particular fragment.

Comment: Hi Palak.could you give details explaination with code.so it will helpful to me