# How to get the fragment from Backstack position

Tags: android, android-fragments

```
    for(int entry = 0; entry < mFragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount(); entry++){
       Fragment fragment=  mFragmentManager.findFragmentById(mFragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(entry).getId());
        Log.i(TAG, "Found fragment: " + String.valueOf(fragment.getClass().getSimpleName()));
    }
```

The above code returns null, is there any better solution to get the fragment using its position in backstack.

Comment: you need List or Position ?

Answer (score 1):

To get the latest fragment in backstack,

```
FragmentManager.BackStackEntry backEntry=getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(getActivity().getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()-1);
    String str=backEntry.getName();
    Fragment fragment=getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(str);
```

Check this [How to resume Fragment from BackStack if exists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9787891/2826147)
and this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9787891/2826147) will give you more detail.