# Android. Determine the first fragment in the activity

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, fragment-backstack

Is it possible to determine with which fragment the activity was started. For example, I have an activity, and several fragments, I need to return from the last fragment to the first, is it possible to implement it.

Is it possible to achieve this without using Android Navigation, Cicerone and etc.

**Note:** the first fragment may no longer be in the backstack

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9702216/get-the-latest-fragment-in-backstack

Comment: Use Android Navigation to achieve this. [This codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-navigation?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0) will be helpful